# Notification icon that looks like 3 stacked horizontal bars

Tags: notification-icons

What is this notification icon that looks like 3 stacked horizontal bars?

[image]

Comment: It should be from a 3rd party app you recently installed in your phone. Its not specifically particular to an android services. It indicates the app is running the service in the background that you are aware of and most of the apps give an option to turn it off. Look for something like `Hide notification icon` option.

Answer (score 8):

Probably the simplest thing to do is to browse through your installed apps and see if there's an app that uses that icon.

It looks to me like the [Flipboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flipboard.app) icon.